Updated Visual Studio now the function Blazor.disconnect is not found
I updated Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.11.4.
Now when I try to log in to my Blazor app (users database is in Azure), I get the error

TypeError: Blazor.disconnect is not a function
in window.addEventListener(beforeunload") callback

screen capture
Any ideas why this is not working anymore in the updated Visual Studio?
I have updated all Nuget packages used, but I still have the same issue

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

check correct initialization and modify event listener
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    if (typeof Blazor !== 'undefined' && typeof Blazor.disconnect === 'function') {
    enter code here
        Blazor.disconnect();
    }
});
console.log('Blazor object:', Blazor);

